# How to implement "Loading" in UITableView when scrolling down?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am working on iPhone application . This application contains plenty of web services. I need to show list in UITableView with page by page. How to show "Loading"  and call web service when scrolling down the UITableview ? Please help me..

Comment: Thanks for removing the exclamation points!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are adding a custom cell to the bottom of your table view to indicate the end of the current data set. When you create that cell, set its `tag` property to a meaningful constant you've previously defined, like `END_OF_TABLE_CELL`.

Then use the delegate method `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` to check if the cell about to display is your custom cell, and trigger a reload of the table's datasource.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 //check your cell's tag
 if (cell.tag == END_OF_TABLE_CELL) {
      //Call your custom method to fetch more data and reload the table
     // You should also remove this custom cell from the table and add one at the bottom
 }
}
```

This way you will have a table that refreshes itself whenever a user scrolls down far enough to bring the custom cell into view.

Good Luck!

Comment: I did exactly this and it worked like a charm. A more in-depth tutorial for this approach: http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/8-automatic-uitableview-paging.